# SQL request for report

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a problem with the writing of the request for the report, which reflects the number of events is created and updated every day.

The table includes:

FieldTypeComment

```
id int (11) NOT NULL
name varchar (255) NULL
created_on datetime NOT NULL
updated_on datetime NOT NULL
```

Created and updated date may not coincide.

request:

```
SELECT 
    z.date_created, 
    SUM (IF (z.date_created = z.date_updated, 1, 0)) AS created, 
    SUM (IF (z.date_created! = Z.date_updated, 1, 0)) AS updated
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING (e.updated_on, 1, 10) AS date_updated, 
        SUBSTRING (e.created_on, 1, 10) AS date_created 
    FROM 
        event e
) z
GROUP BY 
    z.date_created
```

I need the following result:
[image]

Does not give the desired result, because does not show all dates.

Comment: why use substring? you can use `DATE(e.updated_on)`

Comment: At first you say that you want the number of events created or updated on a given day, but then you say that you don't get all the dates.  That makes it hard to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you want to show dates that don't have any data you need to generate a temp table with those dates and link to that table.

Comment: It query will not get all dates, because fields created_on and updated_on may contain no same dates.

Comment: @korvinko - yes that is exactly my point, create a table with all dates and link to that table (you can make that table dynamically) if the join is not a an inner join you will still have rows for all the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want

- see all dates;
- count `create` in fact;
- count `update` only if it is other date than create:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56254/39

```
SELECT A.*
,(SELECT count(created_on) 
    FROM event WHERE date=created_on) created
,(SELECT sum(created_on<>updated_on) 
    FROM event WHERE date=updated_on) updated
FROM (
SELECT created_on date FROM event
UNION SELECT updated_on FROM event ) A
```

Comment: This query will not display date which contain only in updated_at (unique to the field).

Comment: Now there are all dates in list and updates counted only when differ from create date.

Answer (score 0):

To get number of events created and updated on a particular day, do something like this.

```
select count(*) events
from event
where  
(created_on >= {d '2013-02-10'} and created_on < {d '2013-02-11'})
or
(updated_on >= {d '2013-02-10'} and updated_on < {d '2013-02-11'})
```

This approach takes the time portion of those fields into account.

Comment: I need to display each day in the report for the period of about a year, it's about 365 such requests